# Forward to page using $_GET['page']

Tags: javascript, php

What I'm currently trying to figure out is how I make every page forward to another page, for example, make website.com/page/cool forward to the page.tpl and also make website.com/page/notsocool forward to the page.tpl, and then I'd want to change the contents using Javascript to say welcome to cool or welcome to not so cool.

I'm unsure of how to do this but this is what I have for normal pages,

```
switch ($_GET['page']) {
    case 'page':
        $page = getTemplate('this_page.tpl');
        echo $page;
        break;
}
```

Looking foward to a response!

Let's say we have the URL's,

```
www.stack.com/page/hello, and www.stack.com/page/bye
```

Now I want these both to go to the this_page.tpl file but then I want to get whatever is after /page/ and use that in my Javascript.

Comment: How can I bump my question?

Comment: Have you tried regex matching? You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and match those two URLs and then get whatever was matched and forward it to your js. Also, about forwarding, do you mean redirecting the request or something else?

Comment: Yeah, redirecting but how can I make it so that the url /page/lol for example automatically redirects to the tpl file for /page?

Comment: That can be done via a rewrite of the URL e.g. using mod_rewrite and Rewrite*** commands in Apache, it will automatically match that address and redirect to your preferred site even before it hits your PHP file. Check out examples [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)